# magento 2 migrate Data - illegal offset type in isset or empty

Tags: magento, data-migration, magento2

i tried to Migrate the Magento1 (1.7.0.2) Data to Magento2 (2.0.7).
After i mapped and ignored some Extension Tables i get the following output:

```
[2016-06-17 08:17:52][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: EAV Step]: started
100% [============================] Remaining Time: 1 sec
[2016-06-17 08:17:53][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: Customer Attributes Step]: started
[2016-06-17 08:17:53][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: Map Step]: started
4% [=>--------------------------] Remaining Time: 42 secs


  [ErrorException]
  Illegal offset type in isset or empty
```

Have you any idea, how to fix this or how to find the issue?

Best regards
jinhoff

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For everyone who get this error too.
I have digged deeper at the Sourcecode (data-migration-tool/src) of the migration-tool and added some debug-messages, i have found out which table produces this error.

I have then added this table to the map.xml file and the error was gone.

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/migration/migration-tool-internal-spec.html#logging